# Discrepancy of list append in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am getting a different result when I am using `append(path)` vs. `append(list(path))`

I have the following code to find all paths for a sum:

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right


def find_paths(root, sum):
  allPaths = []
  
  dfs(root, sum, [], allPaths)

  return allPaths

def dfs(root, sum, path, res):
  if not root:
    return
  
  path.append(root.val)
  if root.val == sum and root.left is None and root.left is None:
    res.append(path)
  
  dfs(root.left, sum - root.val, path, res)
  dfs(root.right, sum - root.val, path, res)

  del path[-1]
  

def main():

  root = TreeNode(12)
  root.left = TreeNode(7)
  root.right = TreeNode(1)
  root.left.left = TreeNode(4)
  root.right.left = TreeNode(10)
  root.right.right = TreeNode(5)
  sum = 23
  print("Tree paths with sum " + str(sum) +
        ": " + str(find_paths(root, sum)))


main()
```

This has the following output:

```
Tree paths with sum 23: [[], []]
```

But if I change the `res.append(path)` to `res.append(list(path))` which will then return the correct answer `Tree paths with sum 23: [[12, 7, 4], [12, 1, 10]]`. I am confused on why using the `list` operation would change the answer.

Comment: `.append()` doesn't make a copy of the element being appended.  When you do `del path[-1]`, you affect the list that was appended to `res` in exactly the same way that you affect `path`, because *they're the same object*.  `list(path)` makes a copy (`path.copy()` would be a more usual way of writing that), so it's effectively a snapshot of the contents at that moment in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.append(path)` appends the object `path` itself to the list `res`. After that line, when you modify the `path` object (like `del path[-1]`), the modification is also applied to the appended object in `res`, because, well, they are the same object.

`list(path)`, on the other hand, "copies" the `path`. So this one is now a different object from `path`. When you modify `path` after that, the modification does not propagates to this different object.

You will have the same result if you do `path[:]` or `path.copy()` instead of `list(path)`.

Answer (score 1):

`res.append(path)` appends the actual `path` object, not a copy of it.  So if `path` changes later on, the change will appear in `res` also.

`res.append(list(path))` appends a copy.